# Why do sites still prefer Flash video over the HTML5 video format?

Tags: html5, video, flash

What is it about Flash video that makes sites still prefer it over the HTML5 video format? Why is Youtube's default format Flash, even though they have HTML5 version and they allow you to use it? Why doesn't Facebook even want to show a video if you don't have Flash installed, regardless that they obviously have it in the HTML5 format (because it's available on the mobile touch.facebook.com subdomain of the same URL)?

Comment: Good question. Some of it would have to do with Flash being around a long time and that likely everyone has Flash installed. But that does not explain enough- hence why your question is so interesting.

Comment: Laziness at both ends?  Web developers not updating to HTML4.  Users having non-html5 browsers.

Just guessing.

Comment: I've closed this because it is starting to attract opinionated rants.

Answer (score 2):

The same reason they still support insecure connection modes.... Compatibility. Embedded OS's in some devices and things haven't been updated in a very long time. Perhaps some devices like kiosks are even ie8 on XP without any service packs. Generally, who knows what dinosaurs are out there.

Also I believe html5 player is a fallback. It's prob less code weight (and maintenance) for compat switches if it's a flash first schema rather than doing crazy checks to fallback to flash for the plethora of incompat devices.

Comment: Compatibility sounds like a nice ideology, but is the exact opposite of what Facebook is doing by not showing me a HTML5 video when I don't have a Flash player, when Flash player detection exists.

Comment: @ImNotMike interesting so nothing shows at all if you don't have flash?

Comment: It shows a huge "please install flash" button, as if there's something in it for them. And if you just add "touch" as a subdomain, you get the mobile version of the website, and the working video in a non-flash format. And I don't understand why.

Comment: @ImNotMike Thats wild, i did not realize that i guess. Maybe they have some sort of deal with Adobe that was supposed to be valid for X years, similar to how Netflix is in bed with Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

Companies that use Flash have a workflow with it and have no reason to change, perhaps. They have the tools and the talent to use it so why change? Flash is readily available on Windows still but it's a heavy thing to have, often requires installation and updating and mobile devices can bog down (the reason Apple doesn't allow Flash on mobile).

It should be noted that YouTube now defaults to HTML5 video. My web dev company does not use Flash at all.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is codec support. Even though modern browsers support the most common codecs (H.264, VP8, Theora), the support is inconsistent. For example, VP8 is not supported in IE9 and Safari (due to Apple's involvement in MPEG-LA), Firefox relies on the OS/Hardware for H.264 support, and Theora suffers in both adoption and quality compared to the others.

Because of this spottiness, when a codec isn't supported by a browser, it's common for websites to use Flash as a fallback. [JWPlayer](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference) and [Video.js](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/tech.html) are popular among sites with self-hosted video, and both provide a Flash fallback if a codec isn't supported. It's like a codec polyfill.

Flash also carries RTMP (Real Time Messaging Protocol), which is still the go-to method for streaming live video for a lot of sites. Since Flash is cross-browser, you only have to encode video into one format. This saves bandwidth, and let's the site worry about load balancing instead. Both Facebook and Twitch use this for live streaming.

*Edit: This also explains why these sites want you to use their native apps on mobile. They don't have to worry about format or protocol support if they don't rely on the mobile browser.*

Comment: But why Flash with HTML5 fallback instead of HTML5 with Flash fallback?

Answer (score 0):

Flash tends to have higher compatibility with a lot more web browsers than HTML5 does. Flash has been around for several years, but HTML5 is relatively new. In order for companies to present multimedia to worldwide customers effectively, they would use the tools compatible with the browsers customers have.

Comment: I feel like everyone so far is missing the points. Number one, if you are a desktop PC user on Facebook and you don't have Flash, you get to watch nothing. Number two, if you are on YouTube and you have both, you get Flash. Those are not compatibility-related decisions, especially in Facebook's case. They are preference-based.